# Creating a new object and adding it into another object by calling the respective method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I came across a problem while practising Java.

I have a class *Book* which stores the following information:

> id (int), author and title

and I have another class *BookShelf* which store a collection of books using a Vector/ArrayList and have the following methods:

> addBook: takes in a book object as input, adds the object into the bookshelf, method returns nothing.
>
> returnListOfBooks: takes in no argument and returns a Vector/ArrayList of all books sorting by title in alphabetical order.
>
> returnListOfBooksByAuthor: takes in author as input and returns a Vector/ArrayList of books by that author

**The question that I am stuck at is:**

> main program, BookShelfApp, to do the following:
>
> •  Create a ArrayList of Book objects.
>
> •  Create a BookShelf object.
>
> •  Each time a book is placed on the bookshelf:
>
> o  The program must ask the user for the (a) id of the book, (b) author of the book, and (c) title of the book.
>
> o Create a new Book object.
>
> o Add it into the BookShelf object by calling the respective method.

Here is what i've done so far on the main java.

```
public class BookShelfApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    ArrayList <Book> myList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    BookShelf myBookshelf = new BookShelf(myList);


    System.out.println("Enter ID of the book: ");
    int id = sc.nextInt(); sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the author of the book: ");
    String author = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter title of the book: ");
    String title = sc.nextLine();

    Book myBook = new Book(); //there is an error

}
```

I'm new to java so i'm not quite good at it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your Book object, but I would expect you to define this with:

1. a set of fields representing author, title etc.
2. a [constructor taking those parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

e.g.

```
public class Book {
   private String author;
   public Book(String author) {
      this.author = author;
   }
}
```

so you can then call

```
Book b = new Book("Jeffrey Archer");
```

Note that if you've only defined a constructor with arguments, you *can't* then use a default constructor (as you're doing above) without explictly defining it. The only constructor you'll have available is the one you've declared.

(note : I see you have constructors taking those fields, and setters too. I would prefer the former over the latter. By providing setters, you're making the `Book` *mutable*, and I wouldn't expect a book's author to change. By providing a no-args or default constructor, you can create a `Book` without an author, and that seems strange too)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `constructor` with and without fields like this:

```
 public class Book {

  private String author;
  //constructor without fields
  public Book() {}

   //constructor with fields
  public Book(String author) {
  this.author=author;
  }

  }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have edited my question and added both the class java that i've created so far so that my question would (hopefully) be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ArrayList of books use a  List so that you can hold all instance of book in one list  then create a constructor method that sets the fields representing id, author and book title and add the new bookobjectlist to your Bookshef  :

example :

```
List <Book> mylist = new List<Book>();
```

*construcor*

```
public class Book{
   private int id;
   private String author;
   private String title;


      public Book(int ID ,Strind Author,String Title)
        {
           this.id =ID;
           this.author= Author;
           this.title =Title;
          }

  }
```

After collecting user input of ID, Author and title ,you can either use your setter method or your constructor to add the booh attribute

example

```
   System.out.println("Enter ID of the book: ");
   int id = sc.nextInt(); sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter the author of the book: ");
   String author = sc.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Enter title of the book: ");
   String title = sc.nextLine();

Book myBook = new Book(id,author,title)
```

then add the book to your list of books 
 example :
        mylist.add(mybook);

then ,Add book to shelf  :   BookShelf myBookshelf = new BookShelf(myList);

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already done all of that but I am still stuck at the question where they asked me to create a new Book object and add it into the BookShelf object by calling the respective method. I have edited my question and added both the class java that i've created so my question would be more understandable

Comment: i just add some new hints, take a look at it above

Answer (score 0):

Updated. Good point, Brian Agnew

Minimal conventional implementation of Book class looks like this.

```
package tests;

public class Book {
    private final int id;
    private final String author;
    private final String title;

    public Book(int id, String author, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Minimal implementation of BookShelf looks like this:

```
package tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BookShelf {

    private final ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public void addBook(Book book){
        books.add(book);
    }

    public List<Book> returnListOfBooks(){
        return books.stream()
                    .sorted(
                            (book1, book2)->{
                                return book1.getTitle().compareTo(book2.getAuthor());
                            })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    public List<Book> returnListOfBooksByAuthor(String author){
        return books.stream()
                    .filter(book->{
                                return author.equals(book.getAuthor());
                            })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

returns there utilize Java 8 streams and lambdas, you for sure can use whatever other sorting/filtering method you desire.

Now BookShelfApp class:

```
package tests;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookShelfAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        // I've removed the parameter here, as we do not need to know internal implementation of BookShelf 
        // from BookShelfAll
        BookShelf myBookshelf = new BookShelf();


        System.out.println("Enter ID of the book: ");
        int id = sc.nextInt(); sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the author of the book: ");
        String author = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter title of the book: ");
        String title = sc.nextLine();

        Book myBook = new Book(id, author, title); 

        //Now adding book to the bookshelf
        myBookshelf.addBook(myBook);

        //Now let's output all books in the bookshelf
        for(Book book: myBookshelf.returnListOfBooks()){
            System.out.println(book.getId() + " " + book.getTitle() + " by " + book.getAuthor());
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: 
sort using Collections:

```
Collections.sort(books, (book1, book2)->{
        return book1.getTitle().compareTo(book2.getAuthor());
    });
    return books;
```

Note that this will alter and return the internal list of BookShelf, which is not always good idea. You might be better off copying list and sorting/returning it instead.

Comment: Your minimal implementation of Book is pretty huge, with two constructors, and setters provided too

Comment: There is no constructors in my book ;) And setters are pretty important, so I decided to include them.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, I had forgotten to mention part of the question which I am working on: which was that the Book class should include a constructor, toString, get and set methods. Is there a way to do so if there's a constructor in the Book class?

Comment: yes, I included that in edit: use  Book myBook = new Book(id, author, title);

Comment: if you declare your own constructor in class java no longer provides a default no-arg constructor, so you are forced to use the one you declared

Comment: helped alot! thank you. However, while you're at it, is there a way to do the returnListOfBooks and returnListOfBooksByAuthor method by using ArrayList instead of List? Because I am rather confused with what you're doing on that part... Can I ask you to refer to my codes for those two methods to correct me and help me out?

Comment: Your code would work if Book was comparable (implemented Comparable interface) otherwise you can use Comparator see edit.